# por que me sale el error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql

Lo que pasa es que quiero convertir un valor que viene como tipo texto y convertirlo a tipo datetime para poder hacer un where con la cláusula de between

código de sql:

```
select Nombre,TarifaProv,proveedor from tb_HeadCoun where  Usuario='Z850148' and TipoRecurso='Subcontratado' and FechaInicio between CONVERT(Datetime, '01/01/2019', 103) and CONVERT(Datetime, '31/01/2019', 103)
```

si solo hago la siguiente parte :

```
select Nombre,TarifaProv,proveedor from tb_HeadCoun where  Usuario='Z850148' and TipoRecurso='Subcontratado'
```

si funciona y me sale una fila como resultado pero cuando agrego esta parte me sale el error:

```
and FechaInicio between CONVERT(Datetime, '01/01/2019', 103) and CONVERT(Datetime, '31/01/2019', 103)
```

Comment: tu db debe estar en formato mes-dia-año...

Comment: usa la siguiente funcion SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(date, '13/12/2016', 103), 120)

Comment: qué tipo de dato es la columna FechaInicio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones:

- Al inicio de la consulta usa la opción SET DATEFORMAT dmy
- Configura to servidor en el idioma correcto en vez de utilizar el default U.S. English
- Utiliza fechas en formato ISO 8601 yyyymmdd o yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mss que no son afectadas por las configuraciones de idioma o fecha.